# VueJs 3 TDD a component which depend on external library component

Tags: typescript, jestjs, tdd, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to develop a VueJs 3 component (and composition API) with TDD approach.

The UI : It's a Pop Up that contain a file uploader. The user have to select a file, then a validation button should appears. If the file is a .csv, the button should be active, otherwise the button is disabled and and error message will be displayed above.

The issue is :  The popup component and the file uploader component are in an third part library (its components are prefixed by m-).

The  component emit the event "*file-added*", I work with this event in order to configure the state in the *checkFileValidity* method that set the *isCsvFileStaged* variable that determine the visibility and availability of the button.

My first approach was : "*Hm, I will try to stub the m-file-uploader and emit the event with  a fake file*" but, I failed. Then I tried to set the isCsvFileStaged variable to true before the test but :

1. I failed (Can we use wrapper.setData with composition API ? If yes, how ?)
2. But, above all, I think this way is like "*testing the implementation*" and I think it's a bad idea. So I really want to follow the **Art's Rules** and that's why I wrote here.

There is the code :

```
<template>
<!-- This is the modal in the third-part library -->
  <m-modal v-if="isOpen" data-test="modal">
    <div data-test="modal-content">
        <!-- This is the file picker in the third-part library  -->
      <m-file-uploader
        data-test="file-uploader"
        :label="'Pick a file'"
        :allowedExtensions="['csv']"
        @file-added="checkFileValidity($event)"
      />
      <!-- This button should appear when a file is staged and be enable when the file staged is a .csv -->
      <button
        type="button"
        data-test="upload-button"
        v-if="isCsvFileStaged"
        :disabled="!isCsvFileStaged"
        <span>Import the file</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </m-modal>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, Ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'TddCsvImportModal',
  props: {
    isOpen: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  },
  emits: ['confirm', 'close-modal'],
  setup () {
    const isCsvFileStaged: Ref<boolean> = ref(false)
    const isCsvFile = (file: File): boolean => file.type === 'text/csv'

    const checkFileValidity = (fileList: FileList): void => {
      isCsvFileStaged.value = (isCsvFile(fileList[0])) ? true : false
    }

    return {
      isCsvFileStaged,
      checkFileValidity
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

And the test file :

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import CsvImportModal from '@/modules/group/components/TddCsvImportModal.vue'

describe('TddCsvImportModal.vue', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(CsvImportModal, {
    props: {
      isOpen: true
    }
  })

  it('should display an active upload button if a .csv file is uploaded', async () => {
    const uploadButton = wrapper.find('[data-test=upload-button]')
    
    expect(uploadButton.exists()).toBeTruthy()
    expect(uploadButton).not.toHaveProperty('disabled')
  })
})
```

How to deal with those elements ?

Moreover, I have some warnings in the console when I run test, I don't know how to fix this :

[image: Console warns]

Thank you very much for reading me and I am grateful in advance for your help !